# Windows IStillImage interface: can't get device list

Tags: c++, windows, com

Please take a look at my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Sti.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma  comment (lib, "Sti.Lib")

using namespace std;
void main ()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    PSTI iface = 0;
    hr = StiCreateInstance(GetModuleHandle(NULL), STI_VERSION, &iface, NULL);   
    DWORD numDevices = 0;
    STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION* devices = NULL;
    hr = iface->GetDeviceList(NULL, NULL, &numDevices, (void**) &devices);
    cout << hr;
    hr = iface->Release();
    cin.get();
}
```

GetDeviceList gives me "There was no match for the specified key in the index." Any idea as to what it means? Google doesn't seem to help here.
Everything else is OK (initialization, I mean).

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** It works on Win XP virtual machine, but still fails on host Win 7 x64. Odd.

Comment: I repro, same OS.  Beware that this is a Windows error (0x80070491) which makes the error message a bit suspect.  I don't have any devices on my machine that can supply still images so I'll readily assume that the error really means "there are no devices".  YMMV.

Comment: Nope. I've plugged my camera in - didn't help one bit. However, on win XP I got the same error without camera and OK with a camera plugged in, so you're partially right. We still don't know whether it's my OS or the code that implies a problem.

Comment: Okay, so you *know* that the error means "no devices found".  Finding out why Windows doesn't like your camera is going to require a visit to superuser.com

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for this error on my PC (or so it seems). My OS is quite fresh, I never messed with drivers and so on. Besides, Windows works with this camera just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

STI only works on Win XP, that's all.

Comment: @jm.: You think or you know? Anyway, on Vista and higher one should use WPD, at least for communicating with digital cameras.

Comment: Well I've used some APIs from IStillImage on Windows7: RegisterLaunchApplication and UnregisterLaunchApplication.